# How do i make a symbol appear several specific places in a list of words using Basic Terminal Navigation Commands?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, expression

Here i have a working command showing me all words, more than eight letters, where the third last letter is an a.

`egrep -io '.{5,}a..$' list.txt | sort | uniq | more`

How do i make the shell print the list, but with a dot in between each of the three letters before the a
f.eks: "acc.u.r.ate" or "appre.c.i.ate"

Thanks :)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

this should do...

```
... | sed -E 's/(.)(.)(.)(a..)$/\1.\2.\3.\4/'
```